# Receiving invalid property value

Tags: delphi

It was only recently that I started receiving this error.
I am receiving a run time error that first says 'Invalid Property Value', I click continue and then receive another one saying "Error reading Image2.OnClick : Invalid Property Value".

I use Image2 to manoeuvre between different forms. I have tried deleting all components named "Image2" along with any code under the OnClick event, but still receive the error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no code associated with this runtime error. I get no other errors/warnings pertaining to any specific lines of code. I had a few components named "Image2" on different forms and the runtime error states the invalid property value falls under "Image2". I deleted all of these components but still receive the error

Comment: Any references to `Image2` in your .dfm file(s)? That might give a hint where there is still an `Image2` in your code.

Comment: @S.L.Barth How would I access these .dfm files?

Comment: You can open them with a text editor, or from RAD Studio. To do it in RAD Studio, open the form, click the righthand side mouse button, and choose 'View as Text'. (Disclaimer: that is for Berlin 10.1, might differ in other versions.)

Comment: @S.L.Barth the "View as Text" option has been around for a VERY LONG time.  If you want to open a DFM file in a text editor, make sure the DFM is configured to save in Text format and not in Binary format.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Noted, and thank you for the information!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhere in one of your .dfm files that contain the design time properties of your forms, you have an `OnClick` property that refers to a method that has either been removed, or is invalid in some other way.

Open the .dfm file for the offending form in a text edit, and look for `Image2`. You will then find the offending `OnClick` property setting and should be able to work out how best to resolve the problem.

Comment: Okay thanks I am no longer that runtime error. It is now, however, saying 'Class TButton not found'..

Comment: Well, that's a different issue. Did I answer the question that you asked?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably related to your method's access level.

If your OnClick method is declared as either private or public, try changing its access level to Published or move it right below the form declaration line.

Comment: Thanks. I had this exact problem and my method was public. I moved it below the form declaration and now it works.