# Getting errors "Class TButton not found" and "Error reading Image6.OnClick : Invalid Property Value" when building an old project in a newer IDE

Tags: c++, c++builder, rad-studio, c++builder-11-alexandria, registerclass

I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio 11.

I'm trying to build an old project on a different computer than it was initially developed. I've managed to overcome some minor issues, but I can't get over this one.

The project has a couple of Units, and I stumbled upon an error described here: [Receiving invalid property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51765196/22852187)

> Error reading Image6.OnClick : Invalid Property Value.

I checked the `.dfm` file as advised (I was not able to find an `OnClick` property in `Image6`), and the `TButton` class missing error emerged afterwards. This issue was mentioned in the comments, but I couldn't find any solution.

The biggest issue is that I can't debug the program to see where exactly the error pops up. Also, I am able to search for the `TButton` component on the Palette and add it to the units, although I can't find the `TButton` class on the Palette when I'm in the `.cpp` file instead of the Designer. I'm not sure if this is the problem, because I can't see the `TButton` class on the Palette in the working project, either.

Any ideas how I can make the `TButton` class visible, and run the project?

Comment: "*I can't find the TButton class in the Palette when I'm in the .cpp file instead of Design*" - that's because the Palette is context sensitive. It adjusts itself depending on which content you are working in. You can't drop components on source code, so it doesn't make sense to show components when you are not looking at the Form Designer.

Comment: "*I'm trying to build an old project on a different computer than it was initially developed*" - it is generally NOT advisable to open and build an old project in a newer IDE version. You should instead create a new project fresh and add your existing source files to it as needed.